# How to get parents of all records in hierarchy table?

Tags: sql, presto

This is my table in Presto:

```
ID      ParentId
----   ----------
1       NULL
2       1
3       7
4       2
5       3
6       5
7       NULL
```

I need a query that gives this output:

```
ID      Root
----   ----------
1       NULL
2       1
3       7
4       1
5       7
6       7
7       NULL
```

For each id show the root (go up the tree branch till finding the root)

How can this be done in Presto SQL ?

Comment: Presto does not yet support recursive CTEs.  The only way you can do this with a single query is if you know the maximum depth.

Comment: You can track https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1122 for recursive CTE support.